# How do I find base and dimension of W?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's $W=\left \{(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T : {3x_1+\frac{1}{2}x_2+7x_3} \right \}$. How do I find base and dimension of W?

Comment: Your definition of $W$  in meaningless. Do you mean $3x_1+\frac12 x_2+7x_3=0$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean $3x_1+\frac{1}{2}x_2+7x_3=0$, and that $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$W$ has dimension at most two because $(1,0,0)$ is not in $W$, and since two linearly independent vectors in $W$ are $(-1,6,0)^T$ and $(7,0,-3)^T$, this shows that $W$ has dimension 2, and that the above vectors form a basis for $W$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, as others have pointed out, you mean $3x_1+ \frac{1}{2}x_2+ 7x_3= 0$ then $x_2= -6x_1- 14x_3$ so that any vector can be written in the form $(x_1, x_2, x_3)= (x_1, -6x_1- 14x_3, x_3)= (x_1, -6x_1, 0)+ (0, -14x_3, x_3)=$ $x_1(1, -6, 0)+ x_3(0, -14, 1)$